# Set operators vs set function names

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I wondered what was the recommended/prefered way of working with sets, for example `a.difference(b)` vs `a - b`, as in the first method it is clear we are working with sets, in the second not. However, the `union` operator is `|`, which isn't used for anything else.

Comment: The union operator is bitwise OR.

Comment: You are right, I forgot.

Comment: PEP-218, which proposed the addition of sets, does not make any spcecific recommendation. Use your own judgement.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know